# Como animar elementos que se van creando dinámicamente en un (for loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo una función **que se encarga de crear elementos dinámicamente**, lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
function create_db_container(i) {

   var db = document.createElement("div");
   var db_icon = document.createElement("i");
   var db_label = document.createElement("label");

   var options = document.createElement("div");
   var delete_db = document.createElement("button");
   var edit_db = document.createElement("button");

   $(db_icon).html('dns');
   $(db_icon).addClass('material-icons db_icon');
   $(db_icon).appendTo(db);

   //Label - name of the database
   $(db_label).html(dbs[i]);
   $(db_label).addClass('db_label');
   $(db_label).appendTo(db);

   //Buttons inside options div
   //Drop button
   $(delete_db).attr('name',dbs[i]);
   $(delete_db).addClass('material-icons db_button_label kill');
   $(delete_db).html('close');
   $(delete_db).appendTo(options);

   //Edit button
   $(edit_db).attr('name',dbs[i]);
   $(edit_db).addClass('material-icons db_button_label edit');
   $(edit_db).html('mode_edit');
   $(edit_db).appendTo(options);

   $(options).addClass("options");
   $(options).appendTo(db);

   $(db).attr('id',dbs[i]);
   $(db).addClass('database_container');
   $(db).appendTo("#databases");
   /*
   Aquí he probado a usar
   $(db).appendTo("#databases").fadeIn(500);
   */
}

for (var i=0; i < dbs.length; i++) {
  if (dbs.length == 1 && dbs[0] == "") {break;}
  create_db_container(i);
}
```

Como bien se puede ver en el comentario dentro del guión lo que pretendo es que cada vez que se agrega el elemento **`db`** a **`#databases`** haga un efecto como el **`fadeIn`**.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda posible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero ocúltalo porque cuando lo agregas va a estar visible por defecto. Luego de ocultarlo muy rápido (0ms) lo muestras nuevamente con un tiempo más prolongado:

```
$(db).appendTo('#databases').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1500);
```

Además, de preferencia, no uses un loop para agregar contenido dinámico ya que la ejecución de un loop **no esperará** a que la llamada a una función termine, por el contrario continuará su ejecución, lo que puede llevar a efectos no deseados. En lugar de un for utiliza una función recursiva:

```
function create_db_container (i = 0) {
  if (i === dbs.length - 1) { return; }

  ...

  $(db)
    .appendTo('#databases')
    .fadeOut(0)
    .fadeIn(1500, () => {
      create_db_container(i + 1);
    });
}
```

**Ejemplo**

```js
var dbs = [
'<strong>Primer elemento</strong>',
'<h2>Segund elemento</h2>',
'<label>Tercer elemento</label>'
];

create_db_container();

function create_db_container(i = 0) {
   if (i === dbs.length) { return; }
   
   var db = document.createElement("div");
   var db_icon = document.createElement("i");
   var db_label = document.createElement("label");

   var options = document.createElement("div");
   var delete_db = document.createElement("button");
   var edit_db = document.createElement("button");

   $(db_icon).html('dns');
   $(db_icon).addClass('material-icons db_icon');
   $(db_icon).appendTo(db);

   //Label - name of the database
   $(db_label).html(dbs[i]);
   $(db_label).addClass('db_label');
   $(db_label).appendTo(db);

   //Buttons inside options div
   //Drop button
   $(delete_db).attr('name',dbs[i]);
   $(delete_db).addClass('material-icons db_button_label kill');
   $(delete_db).html('close');
   $(delete_db).appendTo(options);

   //Edit button
   $(edit_db).attr('name',dbs[i]);
   $(edit_db).addClass('material-icons db_button_label edit');
   $(edit_db).html('mode_edit');
   $(edit_db).appendTo(options);

   $(options).addClass("options");
   $(options).appendTo(db);

   $(db).attr('id',dbs[i]);
   $(db).addClass('database_container');

   $(db)
     .appendTo("#databases")
     .fadeOut(0)
     .fadeIn(500, () => {
       create_db_container(i + 1);
     });
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="databases"><dib>
```

Para llamar otra vez a la función `create_db_container` primero *espera* a que termine la animación para obtener un efecto tipo "reveal", esto lo hace mediante un callback a `fadeIn`, el cual jQuery ejecutará una vez la animación haya sido completada.

Comment: Gracias Gustavo por tu aclaración en cuanto al loop for :)

Comment: Para serte sincero, mi solución me parece más práctica. Pero es cuestión de gustos. Como siempre, un gusto poder ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Gustavo se que tu respuesta es práctica y ha sido buena, pero bien sabemos todos que no podemos aceptar dos preguntas, por cortesía tomo tu respuesta como aceptada, pero que conste que las dos son válidas.

Comment: @Javi No debiste cambiarla. Acepta la de Álvaro por favor. Lo mío es un comentario. La respuesta aceptada siempre es **a criterio del OP**, por lo tanto, tú decides, bajo tu criterio, cuál es la más acertada respecto a tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no es un problema de JavaScript sino de estilos. Cuando creas los `div`  con clase "database_container", por defecto estos son visibles, por lo que al hacer el `fadeIn` no ocurre nada (ya están visibles, no hay nada que hacer realmente).

Para que funcione el `fadeIn` debes hacer que los `div.database_container` estén escondidos por defecto (usando `display:none` en CSS) y ya verás el efecto:

```js
function create_db_container(i) {

   var db = document.createElement("div");
   var db_icon = document.createElement("i");
   var db_label = document.createElement("label");

   var options = document.createElement("div");
   var delete_db = document.createElement("button");
   var edit_db = document.createElement("button");

   $(db_icon).html('dns');
   $(db_icon).addClass('material-icons db_icon');
   $(db_icon).appendTo(db);

   //Label - name of the database
   $(db_label).html(dbs[i]);
   $(db_label).addClass('db_label');
   $(db_label).appendTo(db);

   //Buttons inside options div
   //Drop button
   $(delete_db).attr('name',dbs[i]);
   $(delete_db).addClass('material-icons db_button_label kill');
   $(delete_db).html('close');
   $(delete_db).appendTo(options);

   //Edit button
   $(edit_db).attr('name',dbs[i]);
   $(edit_db).addClass('material-icons db_button_label edit');
   $(edit_db).html('mode_edit');
   $(edit_db).appendTo(options);

   $(options).addClass("options");
   $(options).appendTo(db);

   $(db).attr('id',dbs[i]);
   $(db).addClass('database_container');
   //$(db).appendTo("#databases");
   

   $(db).appendTo("#databases").fadeIn(500);
   
}

var dbs = ["db1", "db2", "db3"];

for (var i=0; i < dbs.length; i++) {
  if (dbs.length == 1 && dbs[0] == "") {break;}
  create_db_container(i);
}
```

```css
.database_container { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="databases"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias Álvaro, no se como no he podido caer en ello :/